# Bootstrap Modal.js understanding code

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

hey guys i am new to javascript and just dabbling in jquery and bootstrap , i have a small difficulty .

have a look at this plugin line :  [Modal.js line 279](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L297)

the line is `if (typeof option == 'string') data[option](_relatedTarget)`

now if i replace this line with

`if (typeof option == 'string') Modal[option](_relatedTarget)` // i have replaced data with Modal

i get an error :

> TypeError: Modal[option] is not a function

now why am i getting this error , after all is data not Modal itself ??

if you look at the previous line you will see the following declaration :

```
if (!data) $this.data('bs.modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
```

can somebody explain why am i getting this error ?

Thank you .

Alexander.

Comment: Are you editing bootstrap's javascript? What are you *trying* to do?

Comment: @Tomanow , trying to understand Javascript , and no not trying to edit anything !

Comment: Modal is constructor function and data is instance of it, you would need to create insance of it, the same as in line 296.